# Using existing keystore with new project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-keystore

I have got the keystore with which I signed the old application, which is available on the Google Play Store.

**Can I use the same keystore for a new project and update my app (on Google Play Store)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> May i use that for my new project and update my Google play app?

**Yes,** You can use that keystore for many applications.

No need to generate a new keystore.

**Same keystore will help if you want to update or modify the application**. At that time you need to sign your application with the same key throughout the
expected lifespan of your applications. There are several reasons why
you should do so

check more details [Signing Considerations Document.](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#considerations)

Comment: Please consider this. i already published my app in google play store and i safe my keystore in my machine but i cannot find my source code. Is it possible to create new project and use existing key then update my old project what i post earlier.

Comment: yes, you can do that. inform me if issue not solved.

Comment: @Manikandan if you have already launched an APK on Play Store, it will only match the keystore signature. I launched a revamped version of the app last year, and it didn't cause me any issues. But make sure that users upgrading to your new version won't get any crashes (caused by conflicting `SharedPreferences`, etc).

Comment: yes, you are right. it wont make any issue if using same keystore. hope @Manikandan is not facing any issues now.

Comment: @AmitVaghela 
If i change package name and application ID in new project then would it work?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can use same key for multiple projects.

But make sure to keep this key at safe place, because once you lost this key you will not be able to update your existing projects.

Comment: Please consider this. i already published my app in google play store and i safe my keystore in my machine but i cannot find my source code. Is it possible to create new project and use existing key then update my old project what i post earlier.

Comment: yes its ok if your app is in app store in that use have to use the same keystore its mandatory

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use the same with same password

Comment: Please consider this. i already published my app in google play store and i safe my keystore in my machine but i cannot find my source code. Is it possible to create new project and use existing key then update my old project what i post earlier.